# Counter PHP tutorial ,missing parts?

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to create  a counter for my website using mysql and php.I followed this tutorial http://www.squidoo.com/php-mysql-visitors-counter-tutorial ,but it does not work for some reason.And i could not understand the following code :

```
echo "This webpage has got a total of ".getCounter('hits')." hits from which ".getCounter('unique')." unique.";
```

Hits ?? Unique ?? where does he get those params from ? he doesn't mention that anywhere.
PLS HELP ,i'm a newbie

Comment: where is your code ?? What exactly u want to count, be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hits" and "Unique" are used in this function definition:

```
function getCounter($mode, $location = NULL) {

    if(is_null($location)) {
         $location = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    }

    if($mode == "unique") {
        $get_res = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM counter WHERE location = '$location' ");
    }else{
        $get_res = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM counter WHERE location = '$location' ");
    }

    $res = mysql_num_rows($get_res);

    return $res;

}
```

The query that gets called depends on the string you pass as an argument. It's terrible but that's the way it's written.

Comment: ohh,i understand now but it does not seem to work on my dynamically loaded pages

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Are you getting an error message? Is it giving you wrong information?

Comment: the getcounter('hits') and getcounter('unique') is always 0 ,cause nothign gets  loaded into my databse

Comment: Are you able to run queries on your database directly? either through PHPMyAdmin or command line?

Comment: yes,i use php commands on a database created in heidisql that's how i establish the connection to the database and load my page(select,insert,update,anything works) , but for some reason the counter.php that i include in my page does not seem to use that connection

Answer (score 0):

> 1. counter.php
>      This file will contain the script for the functions of the counter

Take a look at the tutorial again. Is counter.php loaded in your setup?

Comment: it just returns 0 always, well my pages are dinamically loaded from my database ,maybe that's the problem?